# 'Automatically link new work in this build' and retention policy

Tags: azure-devops

From AzureDevOps Build pipeline, you can do 'Automatically link new work in this build'. After enable this option, a link will added into Work Item when a build is successful.

Also there is a Retention Policy applied on the build pipeline.

The question is that when a build has already **linked** to a work item, after retention policy applied, will this **linked build** be clean up ?

Answer (score 1):

> The question is that when a build has already linked to a work item, after retention policy applied, will this linked build be clean up ?

Sorry for this late reply, but still hope this answer can give you or someone else who has this issue any help.

The short answer is yes. **The linked build would be clean up after retention policy applied**.

I test this with a sample project, which enable the `Automatically link new work in this build` and set the `Retention policies` with **1** Days to keep. Then I build the project at 1/28/2019 (UTC +08:00), it was deleted today:

[image]

Then I check the work item which linked build:

[image]

When you click the link build, it will jump to the deleted build:

[image]

So, when a build has already linked to a work item, after retention policy applied, the linked build would be clean up.

Hope this helps.